# Semaphores leftovers on linux machine

Tags: linux, process

While managing large Linux servers environment I see sometimes machines reaching their IPC limits, more specifically, semaphores leftovers:

```
Linux #ipcs -u | grep -B2 sema
------ Semaphore Status --------
used arrays = 1024
allocated semaphores = 3072

Linux #ipcs -l | grep -B2 sema
------ Semaphore Limits --------
max number of arrays = 1024
max semaphores per array = 250
max semaphores system wide = 256000
max ops per semop call = 32
semaphore max value = 32767
```

Looking at particular semaphore, i can only see the last process accessed the semaphore:

```
Linux #ipcs -s -i  63636429

Semaphore Array semid=63636429
uid=11488322     gid=12460       cuid=11488322   cgid=12460
mode=0666, access_perms=0666
nsems = 3
otime = Mon Jul 14 16:02:09 2014  
ctime = Mon Jul 14 16:02:05 2014  
semnum     value      ncount     zcount     pid       
0          1          0          0          11551     
1          0          0          0          11551     
2          0          0          0          11551
```

None of the processes exists anymore.

What's the most effective way to troubleshoot the issue and find why the semaphores are not deleted properly?

Another, more general question, is why OS doesn't reap unused semaphores in the manner similar to orphaned processes?

Comment: Semaphores are typically used by multiple processes. As such they aren’t removed automatically. I’m sure someone will provide an in-depth answer though.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, remove the semaphore when the last process is not running, but be cautious, maybe semaphore is used by other processes.

```
for semid in `ipcs -s | cut -d" " -f 2` ; do pid=`ipcs -s -i $semid | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 | awk '{print $5}'`; running=`ps --no-headers -p $pid | wc -l` ; if [ $running -eq 0 ] ; then ipcrm -s $semid ; fi ; done
```